# "Solutions Engineer" or "Solution Engineer" for job role title

Tags: grammatical-number

I keep seeing different terms **"Solutions Engineer"** or **"Solution Engineer"** in job role descriptions. I'm not a native English speaker, but to me, "Solutions Engineer" (plural) somehow looks 'better' as you usually work on multiple and not one solution. What's your take on this, what would you prefer?

Comment: Not only that, but coming up with a **single** solution to a problem could be a "do-or-die" situation, whereas several strategic approaches could be considered and presented, to be evaluated in terms of cost/performance ratios and other factors that can't be quantified, such as satisfaction. Also, a singular *solution engineer* might be thought to be some kind of chemist.

Comment: Is it a Chemicals Engineer? We know a house painter paints more than one house. Also, the word solutions is a bit fluffy and overused - that's why you know that every consulting firm claiming not to be a *body shop* but a *solutions provider* is, in fact, a consulting firm.

Comment: Why would anyone want an  engineer who doesn't provide solutions?

Comment: @HotLicks — Because they might want something more solid. But, then I’m only a scientist, not a linguist. However, the idea of describing oneself or one’s company as providing solutions rather than goods or services is an abomination of the English language, opening one to ridicule. If you shovel shit, say so. Do not describe yourself as an excrement removal solutions engineer.

Comment: I think there's some confusion here. A capital *S* Solution Engineer typically works with a Sales team to fit their company's products and services to a prospective client's needs. It's a legitimate question. Sales Leader uses the plural form, while a Chief Product Officer uses single, but both normally have more than one sale or product. The role exists because each solution requires some degree of special handling. Companies that provide "solutions" go beyond a product/service, and may work on integration, migration of systems, and other parts of the problem.

Comment: I must confess that I've never seen either of these terms before. As modifiers of  engineer, I have seen chemical, mechanical, nuclear, electrical, aeronautical, materials, etc. What exactly is a solution or solutions engineer? You might as well go with some equally nebulous term like solution provider or problem solver. What am I missing here?

Comment: @RichardKayser Solution(s) Engineer is commonly used for a Presales role. Solutions Engineer, Sales Engineer, Presales Engineer, all pretty much the same. If you look on LinkedIn for example, it's quite common.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "noun+noun" construction the attributive noun traditionally should be in singular as in **job descriptions** :-) or **book lover** (who, we assume, likes reading more than one book). However, in modern usage, especially in business, the plural forms are quite common.

If you ask which one sounds better to me, I'd go with **solution engineer**. (Actually, I'd prefer something less pompous, but I'm old and grumpy, so...).

Comment: That makes sense, if you say it both in plural: "Solutions Engineers", it would sound weird. Never thought of it this way. I agree regarding the preference, it's pretty abstract and similar to the generic "consultant" term, but that's (unfortunately) commonly used in HR it seems (and so, to be found more easily by recruiters, it helps putting such terms into ones profile)

Comment: I think "Solutions Engineers" sounds weird bc we instinctively feel that the attributive "solution" sort of works as an adjective here. And adjectives usually don't take the plural "-s".